# Нужен совет в написании кода

Tags: android, kotlin

Вопрос, как и куда мне добавить формулу a+b+c+d, чтобы в зависимости от положений switch добавлялась или убиралась из этой формулы переменная?
Например, формула 2+3+4. На главном экране у меня стоит switch к 5 и 7. Когда switch 5 в положении true, в изначальную формулу добавляется слагаемое 5, когда свитч выключен, формула не изменяется. Тоже самое и для цифры 7.

Comment: что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Не знаю, как написать такую программу. Начал программировать около недели назад, по бесплатным курсам на Ютубе (финансовых возможностей не хватает на нормальное обучение программированию), пытаюсь написать приложение. Не понятно, какие функции надо использовать и как написать код, чтобы он работал так, как надо для моего приложения.

Comment: Вопрос написан не очень понятно, но если я правильно понял, то просто там где switch true считайте a+b+c+d а там где false a+b+c., меняйте формулу в зависимости от положения switch'a

Comment: Раз у вас сложение, при выключенном добавляйте 0 вместо 5 или 7. Формулу менять не придется, только параметры.